# Flask MethodView No request object in def Post(self)

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to send a html5 form to flask using the class based MethodView. From what I understand, the def post(self): should contain a request object with the form attributes. However, when I try the below code I get `"NameError: global name 'request' is not defined"`

flask:

```
from app import app
from flask.views import MethodView
from app import app
from flask.views import MethodView

from flask import url_for

@app.route('/')
def index():
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')


class ImageShareForm(MethodView):

    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        print (request)


app.add_url_rule('/imageshareform/', view_func=ImageShareForm.as_view('imageshareform'))
```

html:

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group btn-group-ls well col-md-5">
        <legend>Region</legend>
        <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="regions" id="IAD" value="IAD" checked>
        <label for="IAD" class="btn btn-default region">Virginia</label>
        <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="regions" id="ORD" value="ORD">
        <label for="ORD" class="btn btn-default region">Chicago</label>
        <input class="form-inline" type="radio" name="regions" id="DFW" value="DFW">
        <label for="DFW" class="btn btn-default region">Dallas</label>
        <input type="radio" id="HKG" name="regions" value="HKG">
        <label for="HKG" class="btn btn-default region">Hong Kong</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
        <label for="producerUsername">Producer Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producerUsername" placeholder="Enter producer's username" >
        <label for="producerApiKey">Producer Api Key</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="producerApiKey" placeholder="Enter producer's api key" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
        <label for="consumerUsername">Consumer Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="consumerUsername" placeholder="Enter consumer's username" >
        <label for="consumerApiKey">Consumer Api Key</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="consumerApiKey" placeholder="Enter consumer's api key" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group well col-md-5">
        <label for="imageUuid">Image UUID</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="imageUuid" placeholder="Enter images's image Uuid" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" formenctype="multipart/form-data" formaction="/imageshareform">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out I needed to import request that comes with Flask